# Does anyone know how to enable "Massively Reduced Disk Usage for Wallets" feature in Bitcoin Core 0.12.0?

Tags: bitcoin-core, storage, pruning

Based on the release note https://bitcoincore.org/en/2016/02/23/release-0.12.0/. Users will be able to run a full node while only storing around 2GB of data.

What should I do to enable this feature to reduce storage consumption of my wallet?